# extracting data from pdf and make a list of lists

Tags: pandas, list, pdf

I need some help extracting and manipulating data from a pdf.
pdf in question below, link: https://www.england.nhs.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/national-tables-5-mgml-v3.pdf
[national dose band screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxBC5.png)

What I want is to create a list of lists, with the items on columns 1 and 3, like this one: oxalirange = ([5.75, 6.24], [6.25, 6.74], [6.75, 7.24],...

I know how to extract the pdf as an excel table via Camelot and pandas, and then what I have been doing is manually compiling the list, so what I'd like to know is how to automate that via python and pandas (or any other python library)
I am happy to be pointed out to the most relevant website so I can find the info myself.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uses xlrd library in python to read an excel file here is a link to their documentation, However it will be limited to .xls files only (old excel)

https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

but here is a list of alternative libraries related to excel

https://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play, see which one works best.